# Copying a range from one sheet to a specific range in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The data from the form response sheet "EFS" needs to be copied into the "QE" sheet. The range for the destination sheet does not start in Column A Row1, instead, it should start in Column C of row 3. As this is an active form when a new entry is made that entry needs to be copied to the last row on the destination sheet "QE"  This is what I have so far. I am getting an error,

> The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 26751 but the range has 20. (line 15, file "QETaskList")

I've tried to change the range but I get other errors.

```
function CopyGradesToQETaskList() {

var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1PK-nMvqIoXaL1nrYPRIWr72I5IQ3wd9sjeztMtR9J1M"); 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('EFS'); 


var lastRowSource = ss.getLastRow();
var source = sss.getRange("A2:p2" + lastRowSource);    
values = source.getValues();

var TargetSource = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var TargetSheet = TargetSource.getSheetByName('QE');
var last_row = TargetSheet.getLastRow();
TargetSheet.insertRowAfter(last_row)
var tsRange = TargetSheet.getRange("C2:R2"+last_row);
tsRange.setValues(values);

}
```

Comment: What is the size of the range to be copied?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function CopyGradesToQETaskList() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SSID"); 
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('EFS'); 
  var src=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),1,1,16);
  var vA=src.getValues();
  var tss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var tsh=tss.getSheetByName('QE');
  var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,3,1,16);
  trg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that `lastRowSource` and `last_row` hasn't the same value.

Another problem is that the expressions  `"A2:p2" + lastRowSource` and `"C2:R2"+last_row` are wrong

Let say that both sheets have the same number of rows. The problem is that if the last row on both sheets where 10, the result of the above expressions are `A2:p210` and `C2:R210` respectively while it's very likely that you expect `A2:p10` and `C2:R10`.